# Why Anchor Boxes in Object Detection

Tags: neural-networks, object-detection, yolo

What I understand from the anchor boxes is that they are predefined set of boxes of different sizes and shapes. A model like YOLO predicts offsets of the coordinates for each anchor box along with confidence and class scores. Please Correct me If I am wrong here.

What is the purpose of anchor boxes? why don't we just make the model predict multiple bounding boxes per cell or grid instead of predicting offsets for each predefined anchor box?

Also how these anchor boxes are used in loss functions of detection models?

This might be a beginner question but I am really not getting this. Any help or explanation will really be appreciated. Thanks